# Raycast from NPC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a NPC in my game and I need him to detect the player position. I'm trying to use a raycast for this purpose. When the player is in front of the NPC, he can detect him. It's a 3D tactical RPG game. Each character can move only one tile per turn.

However, the problem is that he can't detect when the player is on his left, right or behind him. Is there a way that I can change the raycast angles?

I've created this coroutine to use the raycast from the NPC. I call this coroutine inside the Start method:

```
ienumerator detectplayer()
    {
        yield return new waitforseconds(1f);

        ray ray = new ray();
        raycasthit hit;

        ray.origin = transform.position + transform.forward;
        ray.direction = transform.forward;

        vector3 foward = transform.transformdirection(vector3.forward) * 10;

        float duration = 15f;

        debug.drawray(ray.origin, foward, color.red, duration);

        if (physics.raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            print("the game object" + hit.collider.gameobject.name + "is in front of the npc");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Id' say that it is better to calculate bearing of vector from npc to player and npc's bearing, then find angle between those two

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596513/find-the-bearing-angle-between-two-points-in-a-2d-space

Comment: I agree with the above, also, can you let us know what constraints your game has? Depending on the game (tile based, 2D, 3D, etc) the solution may be different.  A possible hint: to change your angle, it looks like you should be changing `ray.direction` to something other than `transform.forward`.

Comment: It's a 3D, tile based game. It's a tactical RPG. Each character can walk only one tile per turn. The NPC just shoots at the character who is being controlled by the human player, if they're in the same line or column of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Unity? in that case you could use the [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) and check the colliders for the player

Example:

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(NPC.transform.position, HOW FAR THE NPC CAN SEE);
for(int i = 0; i < colliders.length; i++){
  if(colliders[i].gameObject.tag == "player"){
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Unity. I'm gonna try this and see what happens. I'm worried that it can't work, because it's a tactical RPG and the characters are in a square each one of them,

Answer (score 0):

I've kind found this "solution" for my problem, I don't know if it is the best way to solve it, however it's working so far:

```
IEnumerator DetectPlayer()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        Ray frontRay = new Ray();
        RaycastHit hit;

        frontRay.origin = transform.position + transform.forward;
        frontRay.direction =  transform.forward;

        Vector3 foward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        float duration = 15f;
        Debug.DrawRay(frontRay.origin, foward, Color.red, duration);

        if (Physics.Raycast(frontRay, out hit))
        {
            print("The game object " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + "is in front of the npc");
        }

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,-transform.right,out hit))
        {
            print("The game object " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + " is on the right of the npc");
        }

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right,out hit))
        {
            print("The game object " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + " is on the left of the npc");
        }

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.forward,out hit))
        {
            print("The game object " + hit.collider.gameObject.name + " is behind the npc");
        }
    }
```

I call this coroutine inside in Start method. Would it be wrong if called it in Update method?